# android webview bind javascript to android code

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Hi i'm setting up my first webview app in android and i try to make my javascript code calls the android code according to this tutorial :
http://android.programmerguru.com/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/

What i'm trying exactly to do is to play a sound on an onclick event like in my website but it's pretty slow and i read many post on it and i understood why i should use another way to do that.

As i found the tutorial i put in the previous link, i tried to make it work in this way but nothing happened. I create "raw" folder and put in it "click.mp3" file.
I'm probably forgetting something but i don't find it...

MyActivity.java files:

```
package com.example.mywebviewapp;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;
MediaPlayer mysound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //Inject WebAppInterface methods into Web page by having Interface name 'Android'
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com");
}

public class WebAppInterface{

    public void soundAndroClick(){
        mysound = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.click);
        mysound.start();
    }
}
```

}

and i call the method soundAndroClick() in my main.js file like that:

```
function soundAndroid(){
    Android.soundAndroClick();
 }
```

Comment: What API level are you targeting? If it's 17+ you need to flag `soundAndroClick` with a [@JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) annotation

Comment: Can you show me an example please?

Comment: `@JavascriptInterface public void soundAndroClick() { ... }`